# SQL 'GROUP BY' to filter an array of 'text' data type

Tags: sql, group-by

I am new to SQL and I an trying to understand the GROUP BY statement.

I have inserted the following data in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table( id integer,  type text);

INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,'start');
INSERT INTO table VALUES (2,'start');
INSERT INTO table VALUES (2,'complete');
INSERT INTO table VALUES (3,'complete');
INSERT INTO table VALUES (3,'start');
INSERT INTO table VALUES (4,'start');
```

I want to select those IDs that do not have a type 'complete'. For this example I should get IDs 1, 4.

I have tried multiple GROUP BY - HAVING combinations. My best approach is:

```
SELECT id from customers group by type having type!='complete';
```

but the resulted IDs are 4,3,2.

Could anyone give me a hint about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I use an online SQL interpreter. https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  The `having` clause needs an aggregation function and you need to aggregate by `id`:

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having sum(case when type = 'complete' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Normally, if you have something called an `id`, you would also have a table with that as primary key.  If so, you can also do:

```
select it.id
from idtable it
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t
                  where t.type = 'complete' and it.id = t.id
                 );
```

Comment: Great answer! Works and I see my mistake in GROUP BY.